# Streaming from google pub/sub using apache flink

Tags: google-cloud-platform, apache-flink, publish-subscribe, google-cloud-pubsub

I spent about couple of hours to find a way to stream from google pub/sub using apache-flink. Does apache-flink have support to stream from google pub/sub ? if yes, how can i do this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no support for PubSub source yet, but there is an open PR for one. You could have a look [here](https://github.com/apache/flink/pull/6594).